# Dystopian near future where paper is banned because it can't be monitored remotely (digitally?)

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

It was a short story set in not so distant and a bit dystopian future.

- Main protagonist (male, I think) lived in a world where paper was
  not used due to rarity/ecological issues/government ban (and thus all communication could be monitored).
- The world wasn't pictured as grim, but rather unnerving.
- The main protagonist is contacted by some underground organization
  (via paper) which needs his help in order to release probably last
  living, and possibly telepathic dolphin.
- The dolphin is not a recurring character, most important thing in the plot is the way main character is portrayed.
- I'm 90% sure that the protagonist was contacted because he works as a journalist or writer.
- I remember that they succeed in the release.

I read the story in question about 4 or more years ago, and it may have been a part of some collection or a shortened "beginner level English" book. I may have read it in Russian, or it may have originally been in Russian, although it most probably wasn't.

I am in no way sure about the details (except the dolphin and paper), so I would be glad for anything even distantly resembling the details.

**So far it's not**

- Johnny Mnemonic
- Easy Travel to Other Planets
- Ishmael in love
- Star Trek (they save a whale, not a dolphin)
- The Uplift series

Comment: A lot of details are a bit off, but I'll ask just to be safe... any chance you're thinking of William Gibson's "Johnny Mnemonic"?

Comment: @starpilotsix   no, doesn't look like it. It's too dystopic - in my story the dystopia part was subtle, plus I don't remember any implants or such. Thanks for trying tho!

Comment: Do you remember roughly when you read it? That might give an upper bound for publishing date.

Comment: @Daenyth it was 4 or more years ago. I remember it being in either English or Russian, and reasonably short (roughly 70 pages, but I may be wrong). It may also have been in a collection of stories, or a short(ened) story in series like "Beginner's English".  
The bottom line is, I cannot recall a publication date, or whether the book I read was old or new, but if I was to guess I'd say it was written after 80s.

Comment: It's probably not what you are looking for, but "Ishmael in Love" by Robert Silverberg is about an intelligent dolphin that can communicate with humans.

Comment: @Ubik yeah, it seems a bit off (way off), but thanks anyway!

Comment: Some similarities with SeaQuest DSV with Roy Scheider? Also present was a dolphin character called Darwin who, due to technological advances, was able to communicate with the crew. It originally aired between 1993 and 1996 that was renamed seaQuest 2032 in its final season.

Comment: @jim nah, it was a book (one thing I am 100% sure of)

Comment: I think they did a few spin off books (A short series of novels based on the characters and concepts depicted on seaQuest DSV were available during the first season of the show. They were: "seaQuest DSV: The Novel (Book 1)" (a novelization of the pilot episode) by Diane Duane and Peter Norwood 1993, "Fire Below" by Matthew J. Costello, 1994,
"The Ancient" by David Bischoff 1994. Nemesis Comics published one issue of a SeaQuest DSV comic book. A second issue was planned, but ultimately not published.), but I suppose there are other discrepancies, for example "where paper was not used"

Comment: @jim yeah, as I recall, paper issue was a big deal there, like a tip that government now controls all communications. Plus, I'm not even sure if the dolphin was telepathic of even speaking in the first place.

Comment: Anything to do with the [*Uplift* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_Universe)?

Comment: @ThePopMachine no, too much Sci-Fi in that one

Comment: There is a story called “The Last Dolphin” by Martin Livings published in "Fables and Reflections 4, 2003". But I cant find the text or a review so no idea if it is the correct story.

Comment: @C.Tomm the publication date and author's overall writing style sure do fit, but I too was unable to find the story online. Thanks for the tip though, it looks promising!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like Ted Mooney's novel "Easy Travel to Other Planets." A dolphin is one of the main characters and there's a description of a neurological illness called "information sickness." The treatment requires isolation from all media in a special facility. The book is available used on Amazon and there may be a full text PDF floating around somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem like it. Thanks for trying!

Comment: There's something deliciously ironic about someone asking about a story with those characteristics, and ending the answer with "... there may be a full text PDF floating around somewhere!"