# Book about dolphins with sonar "telepathy"

Tags: story-identification, books

In the 2000s or 2010s, I read a review about a sci-fi novel in which we learned that dolphins could not only navigate by echolocation, but communicate by it.

In other words, a dolphin could "squeak" in such a way that would appear, to another dolphin's sonar sense, the same as a rock or other solid object.

The author, if I recall correctly, referred to this as telepathy, because one dolphin could transmit "images" to another.  Technically, however, it's transmitting sonograms.

Comment: Hmm. Alastair Reynolds's _Chasm City_ has intelligent dolphins with implants that let them focus their echolocation sounds more precisely, and microorganisms in the water that light up when they're hit by light. That's so they can communicate with humans, though.

Comment: There might be something about it in David Brin's *Uplift* cycle. I seem to remember one of Creideiki's companions having a name that, in sound, "resembled" his distinctive nose shape.

Comment: Also possibly _[World of Ptavvs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ptavvs)_ by Larry Niven.

Comment: [Sapient Cetaceans](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SapientCetaceans) trope.

Comment: @Spencer It's definitely not _World of Ptavvs_. Like most of Niven's ''Known Space" series, I've read it at least once. And I appreciate the TV Tropes link, but Stack Exchange frowns on link-only answers and probably link-only comments. I found only one entry there about communicating by sonar.

Comment: @ShawnVWilson Link-only comments are perfectly OK as long as they help with what they're commenting on. They help prevent link-only answers.

Answer (score 4):

This may be [*Into the Deep*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/292545.Into_the_Deep) by Ken Grimwood. The dolphins in this book manage to communicate with humans as well.

> Set on land and beneath the oceans, Into the Deep reveals, once again, Ken Grimwood's exceptional talent for blending fantasy and reality. One part thriller, one part spiritual adventure, the exhilarating story at the heart of Into the Deep involves a hard-hitting journalist, a beautiful scientist, a globe-traveling engineer, and a venerable Portuguese fisherman. Vastly different, their lives are about to intersect and to become irrevocably changed by a school of dolphins--as the fate of the world hangs in the balance. With the drama that unfolds from a silent war waged at the sea's greatest depths and from a single, fateful discovery, Into the Deep takes a tantalizing glimpse at the optimistic future this planet might achieve if humans and the creatures of the deep could learn to share and defend its remarkable bounty.

Comment: Is there, by any chance, any mention of paper being banned? If there is, this may be the answer to [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138170/70236) as well.

Comment: sorry, that sounds like a different story from Into the Deep. No mention of paper being banned.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

*The Dolphins of Pern*
Novel by Anne McCaffrey

Synopsis from Amazon:

> Two boys, one of them a dragonrider, re-establish crucial contact
>   with the wise dolphins, the legendary "shipfish" of Pern.

Comment: Please tell me you are joking! She didn't write a dolphin book - no, please! OMG I googled it and she did. Sigh.

Comment: @RedSonja I enjoyed the first few, but then imo, the books became ridiculous. I have a daughter who at nine through twelve  loved them all. Fair enough, they were written for her age group imo.

Comment: Some of the early Pern stories were Hugo winners! Hard to imagine now.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  McCaffrey got greedy and soon stopped caring about anything other than word counts and paycheques. And when Todd took over -- a joke. We read aloud to each other in our family and I was thrilled when our daughter lost interest in Pern.

Answer (score 0):

## [*Startide Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising) (1983), by David Brin

Aboard the starship *Streaker*, Thomas Orley — a human who is skilled in this dolphin communication method — creates a sound-shape to pull Captain Creideiki (a dolphin) out of a blue mood:

> Orley noticed his friend’s mood. He pursed his lips and whistled. His breather mask amplified a faint sound-shadow picture. The little echo danced and hopped like a mad elf from corner to corner in the oxywater-filled chamber. Workers in the weapons pod lifted their narrow, sound-sensitive jaws to follow the skipping sonar image as it scampered unseen, chittering in mock sympathy.
>
> ...
>
> The sound-wraith vanished, but laughter remained.
>
> Creideiki let the mirth settle. Then, from his brow came a pattern of chamber-filling clicks that merged to mimic the sounds of thunderclouds gathering. In the closed room those present heard raindrops blown before the wind. Tom closed his eyes to let the sound-image of a sea squall close over him.
>
> — *Startide Rising*, Chapter 11: Creideiki & Orley

*Startide Rising* is the second novel of [The Uplift Saga](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41134-the-uplift-saga) by [David Brin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Brin).

You can [borrow *Startide Rising* as an e-book from The Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL58710W/Startide_Rising).

[image: Front cover of Startide Rising]

Comment: the "transmitting images" part fits, but as far as I can remember it's never referred to, even metaphorically, as "telepathy" in the book ...